# redis-dart throws SocketException

Tags: dart

I am trying to get an example from https://github.com/ra1u/redis-dart to work but I keep getting the following error. Any Ideas why i am getting this?

Unhandled exception: Uncaught Error: SocketException: OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.

```js
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:redis/redis.dart';

main() {
  
  RedisConnection conn1 = new RedisConnection();
 RedisConnection conn2 = new RedisConnection();
 Command command; //on conn1
 PubSubCommand pubsub; //on conn2

 int test1cnt = 3; //expecting 3 messages
 int test2cnt = 1; //expecting 1 messages

 var testmessages = [["PUBLISH", "aaa", "aa"],
 ["PUBLISH", "bbb", "bb"],
 ["PUBLISH", "ccc", "cc"]];

 return conn1.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379).then((Command cmd) {
  command = cmd;
  return conn2.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
 }).then((Command cmd) {
  pubsub = new PubSubCommand(cmd);
  pubsub.psubscribe(["a*", "b*", "c*"]);
  //test1
  pubsub.getStream().listen((msg) {
   for (var m in testmessages) {
    if (msg[2] == m[1]) {
     test1cnt--;
     return;
    }
   }
   throw ("did not get msg");
  });
  //test2
  pubsub.getStream("a*").listen((msg) {
   for (var m in testmessages) {
    if (msg[2] == m[1]) {
     test2cnt--;
     return;
    }
   }
   throw ("did not get msg");
  });
 }).then((_) {
  for (var msg in testmessages) {
   command.send_object(msg);
  }

  Completer comp = new Completer();
  Timer timeout = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () {
   conn1.close();
   conn2.close();
   if ((test1cnt == 0) && (test2cnt == 0)) {
    comp.complete("ok");
   } else {
    comp.completeError("didnt got exepeted number of messages");
   }
  });
  return comp.future;
 });
}

// helper function to check
// if Stream data is same as provided test Iterable
Future _test_rec_msg(Stream s, List l) {
 var it = l.iterator;
 return s
   .take(l.length)
   .every((v) => it.moveNext() && (it.current.toString() == v.toString()));
}

Future test_pubsub2() {
 Command command; //on conn1 tosend commands
 Stream pubsubstream; //on conn2 to rec c

 RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
 return conn.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379).then((Command cmd) {
  command = cmd;
  RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
  return conn.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
 }).then((Command cmd) {
  PubSubCommand pubsub = new PubSubCommand(cmd);
  pubsub.subscribe(["monkey"]);
  pubsubstream = pubsub.getStream();
  return pubsubstream; //TODO fix logic correct, no just working
 }).then((_) {
  //bussy wait for prevous to be subscibed
  return Future.doWhile(() {
   return command.send_object(["PUBSUB", "NUMSUB", "monkey"])
     .then((v) => v[1] == 0);
  }).then((_) {
   //at thuis point one is subscribed
   return command.send_object(["PUBLISH", "monkey", "banana"])
     .then((_) => command.send_object(["PUBLISH", "monkey", "peanut"]))
     .then((_) => command.send_object(["PUBLISH", "lion", "zebra"]));
  });
 }).then((_) {
  var expect = [["message", "monkey", "banana"],["message", "monkey", "peanut"]];
  return  _test_rec_msg(pubsubstream,expect)
    .then((bool r){
   if(r != true)
    throw "errror test_pubsub2";
  });

 });
}

Future test_pubsub_performance(int N) {
 Command command; //on conn1 tosend commands
 Stream pubsubstream; //on conn2 to rec c
 int start;
 RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
 return conn.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379).then((Command cmd) {
  command = cmd;
  RedisConnection conn = new RedisConnection();
  return conn.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
 }).then((Command cmd) {
  PubSub pubsub = new PubSub(cmd);
  pubsub.subscribe(["monkey"]);
  pubsubstream = pubsub.getStream();
  return pubsubstream;
 }).then((_) {
  //bussy wait for prevous to be subscibed
  return Future.doWhile(() {
   return command.send_object(["PUBSUB", "NUMSUB", "monkey"])
     .then((v) => v[1] == 0);
  }).then((_) {
   //at thuis point one is subscribed
   start = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
   for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
    command.send_object(["PUBLISH", "monkey", "banana"]);
   }
  });
 }).then((_) {
  int counter = 0;
  var expected = ["message", "monkey", "banana"];
  var subscription;
  Completer comp = new Completer();
  subscription = pubsubstream.listen((var data){
   /*
      if(data.length != expected.length)
          throw "wrong length";
      for(int i = 0;i<expected.length;++i){
        if(data[i] != expected[i]){
          throw "wrong length";
        }
      }*/
   counter++;
   if(counter == N){
    int now = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    double diff = (now - start)/1000.0;
    double perf = N/diff;
    print("  pubsub perf complete complete , performance ${perf.round()} ops/s");
    subscription.cancel();
    comp.complete("OK");
   }
  });
  return comp.future;
 });
}
```

Comment: You are sure the server accepts connections at this interface and port?

Comment: This is the setup from the example, So Im hoping it does

Comment: You can try for example with `telnet 127.0.0.1:6379` or check with `netstat` if the port is listened to (depending on the OS)

Comment: Yea, I don't see it on the list. So im guessing I am suppose to start a redis server up to listen for connections? I was hoping that I could check other servers on a network and communicate with them if they had the same type of key that authorizes them to. If this cannot do that, is there one that can?

Comment: I don't know Redis, but if you connect to `127.0.0.1:6379` there has to be a service listening and accepting connections otherwise you're out of luck. If there is an Redis service elsewhere and you can of course connect there but the IP and port have to be adjusted.